# I have facebook post id, want to show it's content to user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I could not find any solution to this. 
How should I show post from facebook to user if I have it's id? 
I'd like to show it in dialog similar to the one that is used to send posts to wall.
Other option is to use facebook native application or default webBrowser, however I'd like first option more if it's possible to make.

Comment: you would need a user access token from the user who posted it. and i think you would need the read_stream permission - but you will not get it approved, because it´s only reserved for platforms without a native facebook experience (TVs and stuff).

Comment: @luschn looks like I'm stuck with native app and browser then, thanks